# how to create popup window when pressing numeric keys in sun java wireless toolkit 2.5.2?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, j2mepolish, lwuit-form

I want to create popup window in sun java wireless toolkit when pressing numeric keys on Mobile. I don't know whether it is possible or do need to use some additional technologies for that?

And also I want to draw some strings on the popup window.

Please guide me to get out of this issue?

I have used alert box in j2me but I want one popup window instead of that

Comment: @gnat: I have used alert box in j2me.but i want one popup window instead of that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use a `Dialog`. This is a class from LWUIT which allows you to build a popup window.

More info here:

http://www.lwuit.com/2008/07/pimp-my-lwuit-part-ii-rounded-all-over.html

http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Dialog.html

Comment: Is this not possible with core j2me classes instead of using lwuit?

Comment: In lcdui you only can use `Alert` as a popup window

Answer (score 1):

In j2me there is alert.We can use image in alert also.But for ur scenarios use LWUIT or J2ME Polish.In LWUIT,J2ME Polish there is possible to create pop up window , creating more stylish ui components.

I think we can use LWUIT with normal J2ME,i cannot know surely better u refer the LWUIT site.LWUIT is a sun's (oracle) product